# Is it possible to have H.264 video streaming on Android 5.1 emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, android-mediacodec

An app using [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) to stream H.264 video works flawlessly on Android 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 emulators but the H.264 video streaming does not work on an Android 5.1 emulator:

[image]

Changing the Graphics setting does not make any difference:
[image]

I wonder if it is possible at all to stream H.264 on an Android 5.1 emulator.  Could anyone shed some light on this?

The app gets the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueInputBuffer(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:983)
```